# How can I find out who is connected to my wireless router? (Linksys WRT54g)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

This seems like it would be obvious, but I can't find it anywhere on the screens provided when I log into my wireless router. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious here, but I thought I'd take the chance of looking stupid and ask the community anyway.

Is there a simple way to see all the current devices connected to my wireless router?

It is a LinkSys WRT54-G router if it matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Status -> Local Network -> (button) DHCP Clients Table`?
http://ui.linksys.com/WRT54G/v8.2/8.2.05/StaLan.htm

Comment: Dang, beat me to it, +1

Comment: Don't know if computers not on DHCP will show up, though.

Comment: They won't (as the title would suggest).

Comment: I am only seeing wireless clients here.  None of the hardwired PCs are showing up.  I have a guest PC hardwired which I want to enable MAC filtering for without asking the guest for his MAC.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to enable wireless mac filtering, then click Edit Mac Filter list, where you can see the MAC on anything connected via wlan.

http://ui.linksys.com/WRT54G/v8.2/8.2.05/WFilter.htm

Answer (score 2):

Type 192.168.1.1 in your address bar and click on Status.
Under Status menu, click on Local Network. In Local Network click on DHCP Clients Table. There, are all the computers connected to your Linksys Modem.
If No computers connected to you, the DHCP Active IP Table that pop up, will be empty. Experiment connect with another computer and come back to this menu to check. There will be your pc or laptop where Client Host Name is like: Bob's pc, and IP Adress like 192.168..102, Mac Address like 00.09.10.b5.44 and Expites like 23.43.55

Answer (score 0):

You can access this link in your network:

```
http://192.168.1.1/WClient.htm
```

Where 192.168.1.1 is the ip of your router.

Answer (score 0):

After Logging into your zyxel router control panel go to 
System Monitor>>Traffic Status>>NAT

here you can see the connected wlan users to your router