# Trying to find MAC addresses of computers hardwired to router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

This question is related to [another one](https://superuser.com/q/167269/236863), as I have the same router.  I am looking to set up time-based access restriction for a connected computer, but it's for a guest student so I don't want to explicitly ask for his MAC address.  He is online right now, but using the linked question above and the selected answer, I am only seeing our family's wireless devices listed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using something like [this](http://angryip.org/w/Download) piece of software to discover devices on your LAN, but more than likely your router is acting as a DHCP server, and will contain lease information for the user.

Linksys has [some](http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54G-how-can-I-see-attached-devices/td-p/46395) helpful information as well in their forum, about where to look ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to restrict this persons internet to specific times and to do that, you require the MAC address?

You will need to know some identifying piece of info about his computer like his IP.  Once you've got that, run this in a command prompt:

ARP -A

That will provide you the physical addresses for all devices connected to your network.  If you have the IP of his computer, you will know which device is his and thus get his MAC address.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your router firmware limits what you are able to see, but with something like [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G/GL/GS/GX#Gv8.1) you could probably see the MAC of every connected unit.